# My CSS is only partially working, my text is aligned, but I have no background color or centering of my drop down menus

Tags: html, css

My CSS style sheet is obviously linked properly because my text is centered properly, but my background is not colored and my drop-down menus are not centered, I need help. I have checked and double checked and I don't see any errors but it isn't working.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/travelersaidcss.css">
</head>

<body class="home">
<h1 class="homelang">Home Language</h1>
<div>
<select class="homelang" name="homelang">
    <option value="English">English</option>
    <option value="French">French</option>
    <option value="German">German</option>
    <option value="Dutch">Dutch</option>
    <option value="mandrin">mandrin</option>
</select>
</div>

//backgroundimage//

<div>
<h1 class="destinationlang">Destination Language</h1>
    <select id="destinationlang" name="destinationlang">
    <option value="English">English</option>
    <option value="French">French</option>
    <option value="German">German</option>
    <option value="Dutch">Dutch</option>
    <option value="mandrin">mandrin</option>
    </select> 
    <br />
</div>
<button>Done <img src="images/arrow.png" /></button>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
background-color: rgb(84,163,188);}

h1 {
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 40px;
text-align: center;
color: rgb(0,0,0);
}

div {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

button {
background-color: rgb(84,163,188);
}
```

Comment: If it's the `select` dropdown lists you need to center, just declare `text-align: center;` on the parent `div`. You don't need specify the a(lpha) character at the end of *rgb* if you're not using transparency. Fully opaque rgb fallbacks are actually declared in the event that you happen to encounter a legacy browser that doesn't support them (older versions of IE for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background color appears to work fine. if all you're trying to do is center the dropdowns, add this to your css:

```
select {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Or alternatively, sent text-align: center on the dropdown's container:

```
div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I am viewing my document in goggle chrome and I'm seeing no background color still and no centering, what browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Good way to test if the background-color is being assigned, is to try with something simple that you know will work. Try changing the background-color: red; for example. If it works, you know you are able to assign the background-color. As the previous answer says, you were missing the 'a' from the rgba, and therefore also the opacity.

Answer (score 0):

If I copy and paste this code, your background colors work fine. Your divs are not centered because you must set a width of the div for margin-left / margin-right to work for centering. Right now it is "centered" at a width of 100% with margins of 0.

You can also try text-align: center to center content within your div.